# Invalid character in a base-64 string - ViewState?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

Web application is throwing a handful of these errors everyday.

```
Exception: System.FormatException: Invalid character in a Base-64 string.
   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString)
   at System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState)
   at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load()
```

I think the error's coming from decoding the ViewState, but I'm having trouble just triggering the error. I've never been able to trigger the error in dev, only prod. And even in prod, I can't reproduce the error easily. There are several filters for a dataview on the page, and selecting different values will eventually throw the error, but not in any pattern I can figure out. Sometime's it's the very first time I change a filter, sometimes no combination will.

Comment: Is there a proxy / firewill that might be screwing around with the ViewState when it gets posted back?

Comment: Wouldn't that throw a security exception?

Comment: We have a handful of that too everyday. I suppose hackers are trying weird things in case it breaks something in your server.

Answer (score 0):

it could be one of the reasons below:

- Application Pool Recycling
- Server Farms or Server Clusters
- Proxy servers and Virus Scanners

As first thing  I would Use a specific key in the machine.config to prevent automatic key generation on each process start

Comment: I'm waiting to hear back from the server admin before I make this change. The server's a staging server, but is used as production for some of the apps it hosts. I'll be back as soon as I make the change and see if it works.

Comment: This server is part of a server farm and is used to host some critical web apps, even though it's supposed to be a staging server. If I use a specific key, can't that have potentially negative effects on this or other web apps since it's part of a server farm? I'm a little uncomfortable making machine-level changes because of all the other sites running off this server.

Comment: not if you use the same key on all the boxes that belongs to the same server farm